# while resizing window nav bar text moves

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a static website in which there is  a simple navigation bar.I am not making a resopnsive design.The only problem i am facing is when i resize the window the text moves.How can i avoid this?Following is the code snippet:

```
<div id="menu">
<div id="navcontainer">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Milk</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Eggs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cheese</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Vegetables</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fruit</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>

html, body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #menu{
            width: 50%;
        }

        #navcontainer ul
        {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            list-style-type: none;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #navcontainer ul li { display: inline; }

        #navcontainer ul li a
        {
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: .2em 1em;
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #036;
        }

        #navcontainer ul li a:hover
        {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #369;
        }
```

Comment: you need to give a fixed width for `#navcontainer` .

Comment: But i don't want to give fixed width...Please another solution if possible?

Comment: Try this `#menu {
    width: 100%;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Apply a fixed padding in pixels.

```
    #navcontainer ul li a
    {
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: xxpx xxpx;
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #036;
    }
```

xx -> any number in pixels.

Don't use em. You should probably do the same for the width of the menu. You can try that out.

Comment: Can there be another method without applying fixed width and padding

Comment: Your padding and width has to be fixed otherwise your text would move around when you resize. You could use absolute or fixed, but that would affect your layout.

Answer (score 0):

set the width of the menu to auto:

```
#menu {
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the `ul` movement, then give positioning. Like

```
div#navcontainer {
left: 50px;
position: absolute;
max-width:400px;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the **#menu** width from **%** to **px** (**50%** --> **1349px**) and add **max-width**:1349px; **min-width**:1349px;

```html
<div id="menu">
  <div id="navcontainer">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Milk</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Eggs</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Cheese</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Vegetables</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Fruit</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
  html,
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  #menu {
    width: 1349px;
    max-width: 1349px;
    min-width: 1349px;
  }
  #navcontainer ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #navcontainer ul li {
    display: inline;
  }
  #navcontainer ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .2em 1em;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #036;
  }
```

you can try another **px**
I hope i answer your question ^^

Comment: by the way you can avoid the **position** part

Answer (score 0):

You've assigned a percentage based width to the menu, which means it's width will be 50% of the parent, which also happens to be 50% the width of the window.  If you resize the window to be smaller, the menu will also resize at the same ratio.

Naturally, when content is applied to a page, the web browser is going to make an effort to show it.  To do this, just as when you type a paragraph, if there's no more room, it'll drop to the next line.  That's what inline elements do.  If you want to make it hidden, you can set a height to the menu and then use `overflow:hidden;` to not show the text when it does drop.  The other option is that you can set the text size to be relative to the page width using `vw` units, which are proportional to the viewport width.

```
#menu{
   font-size:10vw;
}
```